# Find license key without backend access

Tags: magento-1.9

Hello is it possible to find my license key for an extension from ftp or ssh?

Which file stores the license key?

Comment: DB = `core_config_data` table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really depends on extension you want to find license for. Very often extensions store licenses in DB in core_config_data table. But also can be used files as stores. So, without extension name it's not possible to say you something more

Comment: Hello the extension is Gomage Lightcheckout.

Comment: Hello I found it inside core_config_data, I searched for Gomage, and there it was. Thanks alot.